# SQL for conditional value ranking

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, ms-access-2010, ranking, ranking-functions

I'm trying to add a column to this table:

```
CREATE TABLE #NEW_HIGH (SYMBOL char(4) not null, CLOSE_DATE date not null, CLOSE_PRICE money)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('A','01/07/2019',31.46)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('A','01/08/2019',32.5)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('A','01/09/2019',34.94)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('A','01/10/2019',34.95)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('A','01/11/2019',34.57)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('B','01/07/2019',12.21)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('B','01/08/2019',11.88)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('B','01/09/2019',12.25)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('B','01/10/2019',12.30)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('B','01/11/2019',11.26)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('C','01/07/2019',22.99)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('C','01/08/2019',22.95)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('C','01/09/2019',22.14)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('C','01/10/2019',23.09)
INSERT INTO #NEW_HIGH VALUES ('C','01/11/2019',22.91)
```

...for the output to be:

```
SYMBOL  CLOSE_DATE  CLOSE_PRICE RANK_BY_NEW_HI
A       1/7/2019    31.46       1
A       1/8/2019    32.5        2
A       1/9/2019    34.94       3
A       1/10/2019   34.95       4
A       1/11/2019   34.57       1
B       1/7/2019    12.21       1
B       1/8/2019    11.88       1
B       1/9/2019    12.25       2
B       1/10/2019   12.3        3
B       1/11/2019   11.26       1
C       1/7/2019    22.99       1
C       1/8/2019    22.95       1
C       1/9/2019    22.14       1
C       1/10/2019   23.09       2
C       1/11/2019   22.91       1
```

Basically I'm trying to add a 4th column called "RANK_BY_NEW_HI" that starts at a value of 1 in row 1 and increases by 1 whenever the next CLOSE_PRICE record (in SYMBOL and DATE order) is higher, and resets to 1 whenever it's equal or lower than the previous CLOSE_PRICE record OR a new SYMBOL begins.

I've spent a few days trying to figure this out, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is really hard to do in MS Access.  Do you have any other databases available?

Comment: I've written everything so far in Access using the SQL viewer (realizing there are syntax limitations), but if you have a suggestion using SQL Server, that would be great.  Thanks for the response, Gordon!

Answer (score 2):

This is much simpler in SQL Server.  You can use `lag()` to identify the peaks, a cumulative sum to identify the resulting groups, and then `row_number()`:

```
select nh.*, row_number() over (partition by symbol, high_grp order by close_date) as rank_by_new_high
from (select nh.*,
             sum(case when prev_cp < close_price then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by nh.symbol order by nh.close_date) as high_grp
      from (select nh.*,
                   lag(nh.close_price) over (partition by nh.symbol order by nh.close_date) as prev_cp
            from #new_high nh
           ) nh
     ) nh
order by symbol, close_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3972c9bc7c9b825bc884f378a2bb6373) is a db<>fiddle.

You are not asking for my opinion, but I would recommend that you do your work in SQL Server rather than MS Access.  It is much more functional database.

Comment: Fantastic...worked perfectly in SQL Server!  Agreed, I'll simply switch it over.  Thanks again, Gordon!